# Js two functions make to work async (independantly)

Tags: javascript

I have two functions: the first starts preloading, the second - make an ajax request, which gets 2 seconds responce.
An id through two addEventListners starts both function.
the task is that the first function dont wait when the second function get a responce.

Comment: Please provide a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of async function in JS for that:

Async functions work on the principle of JS Promises You can read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

The syntax of an async function is

```
async function name(<parameters>)
{
   statements
}
```

Please visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function for more information

Async execution can be achieved like so:

```
 Promise.resolve("World").then(console.log); // then callbacks are always asynchronous
 console.log("Hello");
```

Or simply:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   console.log('1');
}, 2000);

console.log('2');
```

Comment: function likePromise(){
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   unAbleOrAbleSubmit('unAble');
   console.log('Promise:unAbleOrAbleSubmit');
   resolve();
  }).then(function() {
    validateForm();
    console.log('Promise:validateForm');
  });
  console.log('Promise:');
  /*unAbleOrAbleSubmit('unAble').then(function() {
   return validateForm();
  })*/
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
function likePromise(){
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            unAbleOrAbleSubmit('unAble');
            resolve();
        }).then(function() {
                validateForm(); 
        });
    }
```

Despite this code unAbleOrAbleSubmit('unAble'); waits for validateForm();